# Other absolute value definitions in $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, absolute-value

I know these definitions for the absolute value (or module): given a real number $x$, then

$$\bbox[yellow]
{|x|=\begin{cases}x & \text{if } x\geq 0\\ -x& \text{if } x< 0\end{cases}}$$

or

$$\bbox[yellow]
{|x|=\max\{x,-x\}}$$

Are there other definitions in $\mathbb R$ (for example using $\text{sgn}\, x$)?

**PS: The question is referred to high school students.**

Comment: I would not call them *notations*. There is *one* notation: $|x|$. Those are different (though equivalent to each other) *definitions*.

Comment: $|x|=sgn(x)\times x$.

Comment: $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: @StinkingBishop Approved *definitions*! :-)..I use often deepl translator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you are asking is not really notation. The word "notation" refers to how we **write** a particular concept. The concept of "absolute value" has really only one notation: the vertical bars. That is, $|x|$ is the standard notation for the concept "absolute value of $x$".

---

What you are asking is the **definitions** of $|x|$, and in particular, you are listing two **equivalent definitions** of $|x|$.

I can think of two more equivalend definitions for $|x|$:

- $|x| = \mathrm{sign}(x) \cdot x$
- $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: I have improved with definition :-) in fact in the tag there is definition :-)...I'm sorry for the abuse of the translator. I undestand the first definition but the second the students should know that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ for every $x$ real. It's true that equality have the propriety of symmetry, but I think it's a little distorting...

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, it all depends. Every definition demands everything it uses is already defined. For example, the first definition can be eqally circular, since $\mathrm{sign(x)}$ can also be defined as $\mathrm{sign}(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$. But in general, $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the **nonnegative** solution of the equation $x^2=a$. Using this definition, it is perfectly valid to define $|x|$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some I could think of:

- $|x|$ can be defined as the (unsigned) distance of $x$ from the origin.
- It's the even extension of $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ where $f(x):=x$.
- $|x|$ is the unique norm on $\mathbb R$ with
  $|1|=1$.

Comment: For all the user my thank you for the improved of my knowledges.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the first can be used as a definition, feels a little circular